# Quoting an external stage pathname

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to query data from an external stage `@s3data` in the prefix `runs/2022/12/01/15:33:03`. However, if I run this query in Snowflake, it returns 0 results:

```sql
SELECT * FROM @s3data/runs/2022/12/01/15:33:03/
```

But if I run this, I can see all the files with key prefix `runs/2022/12/01/15:33:03/`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM @s3data/runs/2022/12/01/
```

Apparently, Snowflake does not like the `15:33:03` part of the name. Is there some way to "quote" this name in order to allow Snowflake to read from specifically that prefix?

Comment: _Note to readers_ I have cross-posted this question on the Snowflake forums: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do000004pymyKAA/querying-from-an-external-stage-with-a-syntaticallyquestionable-path-prefix

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. I can read or ingest files with copy into from the path ends with the directory called `15:33:03`. The path should not be a problem, maybe the issue with the files or the file_format. Did you create your stage with file_format option? What is the format of the source files?

Comment: @aek I did use `file_format`, yes. The format is Parquet. I can try to construct an MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but I still cant repro, definitely the path with the time in it should be ok for Snowflake. Do you run it from Snowflake UI, right?

Comment: What client are you using -- Snowsight, Classic Web UI, SnowSQL, DBeaver, etc.?

Comment: I used Snowsight when it failed. I can try again in SnowSQL (but let me try the MWE first as well).